# Creating MySQL tables from XML data

Tags: mysql, sql, xml

I'm working with a set of lobbying disclosure records. The Secretary of the Senate [publishes](http://www.senate.gov/legislative/Public_Disclosure/contributions_download.htm) these records as XML files, which look like this:

```
<Filing ID="1ED696B6-B096-4591-9181-DA083921CD19" Year="2010" Received="2011-01-01T11:33:29.330" Amount="" Type="LD-203 YEAR-END REPORT" Period="Year-End (July 1 - Dec 31)">
<Registrant xmlns="" RegistrantID="8772" RegistrantName="CERIDIAN CORPORATION" Address="4524 Cheltenham Drive&#13;&#10;Bethesda, MD 20814" RegistrantCountry="USA"/>
    <Lobbyist xmlns="" LobbyistName="O'CONNELL, JAMES"/>
</Filing>

<Filing ID="179345CF-8D41-4C71-9C19-F41EB88254B5" Year="2010" Received="2011-01-01T13:48:31.543" Amount="" Type="LD-203 YEAR-END AMENDMENT" Period="Year-End (July 1 - Dec 31)">
    <Registrant xmlns="" RegistrantID="400447142" RegistrantName="Edward Merlis" Address="8202 Hunting Hill Lane&#13;&#10;McLean, VA 22102" RegistrantCountry="USA"/>
    <Lobbyist xmlns="" LobbyistName="Merlis, Edward A"/>
    <Contributions>
        <Contribution xmlns="" Contributor="Merlis, Edward A" ContributionType="FECA" Payee="DeFazio for Congress" Honoree="Cong. Peter DeFazio" Amount="250.0000" ContributionDate="2010-09-05T00:00:00"/>
        <Contribution xmlns="" Contributor="Merlis, Edward A" ContributionType="FECA" Payee="Friends of Jim Oberstar" Honoree="Cong. Jim Oberstar" Amount="1000.0000" ContributionDate="2010-09-01T00:00:00"/>
        <Contribution xmlns="" Contributor="Merlis, Edward A" ContributionType="FECA" Payee="McCaskill for Missouri 2012" Honoree="Senator Claire McCaskill" Amount="1000.0000" ContributionDate="2010-09-18T00:00:00"/>
        <Contribution xmlns="" Contributor="Merlis, Edward A" ContributionType="FECA" Payee="Mesabi Fund" Honoree="Cong. Jim Oberstar" Amount="500.0000" ContributionDate="2010-07-13T00:00:00"/>
    </Contributions>
</Filing>
```

As you can see, some `<Filing>` tags also contain `<Contribution>` tags, but others do not.

I see two objects here: contributors (i.e., lobbyists) and contributions (i.e., a transaction between a lobbyist and a member of Congress).

I'd like to load these records into a MySQL database. To me, the logical structure would include two tables: one for contributors (with fields for name, ID, address, etc.) and one for contributions (with amount, recipient, etc., and a relational link to the list of contributors).

My question: am I approaching this problem correctly? If so, does this data schema make sense? Finally, how am I to parse the XML to load it into the MySQL tables as I've structured them?

Comment: i think you are on the right track.  you could use an XSLT to transfor any given XML input file into SQL statements, then run that as a script to load the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I'm using a Python SAX parser to process the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Tradiional approach for these kind of problems is to use an [ETL tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load).

Do you already have such  tool (E.g. Informatica / Talend) in your organization?

Another approach is to write a small utility to parse these XMLs and load this data by creation of master detail relationships in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL version 5.5 you may find the [`LOAD XML`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) command useful.

That being said, `LOAD XML` appears to be geared towards loading data into a single table for a given XML file, so it may not work for your specific files.